# How to get the access token from linkedIn

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api, access-token

I want to to get the access token from LinkedIn.

First I send the request to get the oauth token to `https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken`.

It returns the oauth token successfully then I got the the verifier at `https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=a79d5c7f-8e3d-4a98-8b2d-eca8ce7c4536` this URL it returns the verifier also.

Now I want to get the access token but When I send the request to `https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken` or `http://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken` It said `Page Not Found`. Can anyone tell me what's the problem here?

Comment: Hi, how did you resolved your issue ?

Comment: It's been more than six and a half years now. But if look at the accepted answer, there were some authorization headers were needed to pass with the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request to `https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken` has to be signed properly (involves adding the correct authorization headers, etc)

Comment: I tried putting correct headers too, same URI and same API call i'm making, still no success, can you help me the same